# C# Converting a string containing a floating point to an integer

Tags: c#, parsing, floating-point, int

What is the best way to take a string which can be empty or contain "1.2" for example, and convert it to an integer? `int.TryParse` fails, of course, and I don't want to use `float.TryParse` and then convert to `int`.

Comment: Appart parsing it to a float and then rouding it, I don't see how you could do that...

Comment: `(int)float.Parse("1.2")` - it isn't too much work. Ruby does this though - `"1.234".to_i` yields 1

Comment: @Gishu ... and VB6 does this `Int("1.234")` yields 1. But the question is about C#.

Comment: @MarkJ - yup I noticed.. that's why I just upvoted Phillipe.. parse and cast seems to be the way to do it in C#. The answers below all seem to be much more work in comparison.

Comment: @MarkJ: FYI VB.NET accepts this syntax too but e.g. `Int(1.000000)` returns `1000000` as integer result (might have to do with the fact, that in my country `,` is the default separator, but still worth noting). Edit: Convert.ToDouble does the same, so this is "just" an issue with the Culture-NumberFormat ...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

## Solution 1: `Convert.ToDouble` (culture-dependent)

You may use `Convert.ToDouble`. But, beware! The below solution will work only when the number separator in the current culture's setting is a period character.

```
var a = (int)Convert.ToDouble("1.2");
```

## Solution 2: `Convert.ToDouble` (culture-independent)

It's preferable to use [`IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx) and convert the number in an independent way from the current culture settings:

```
var a = (int)Convert.ToDouble("1.2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
```

## Solution 3: Parse & Split

Another way to accomplish this task is to use Split on parsed string:

```
var a = int.Parse("1.2".Split('.')[0]);
```

Or:

```
var a = int.Parse("1.2".Split('.').First());
```

## Notes

- If you want to handle empty and null strings, write a method and add string.[`IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) condition.
- To get decimal separator for the current culture setting, you can use [`NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx) property.
- You should also keep eye on [rounding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx) to avoid [traps](https://ericlippert.com/2003/09/26/bankers-rounding/).
- Select casting, `Parse`, `TryParse` or [`Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsfy6sz9.aspx) class wisely. Read more at:

  - [How to: Convert a string to an int (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx)
  - [How to: Determine Whether a String Represents a Numeric Value (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384043.aspx)

Comment: +1. Especially for saying that `Convert.ToDouble` uses the decimal delimiter from the thread culture settings (by default the Windows regional settings), and it can be a comma. You can force it to use a dot by passing `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat`

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what's wrong with parsing to a `float` and converting to an `int`. I doubt that any other way would be more efficient but here's an attempt:

```
//allows empty strings and floating point values
int ParseInt(string s, bool alwaysRoundDown = false)
 {
    //converts null/empty strings to zero
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) return 0;

    if (!s.Contains(".")) return int.Parse(s);

    string parts = s.Split(".");
    int i = int.Parse(parts[0]);
    if (alwaysRoundDown || parts.Length==1) return i;

    int digitAfterPoint = int.Parse(parts[1][0]);
    return (digitAfterPoint < 5) ? i : i+1;
 }
```

In order to globalize the code you would need to replace `"."` with [`System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx).

Comment: Don't forget that the decimal delimiter can be different depending on regional settings.

Comment: I added a note about globalization. Thanks!

Comment: Undoubtedly the best one, @Mark. +1 from my side.

Answer (score 2):

```
int a = (int)Math.Round(float.Parse("0.9"));
```

You need to round it first unless you want 0.9f being converted to 0 instead of 1.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to delete everything after floating point using string functions and then convert to int. But seriously I don't think it's better than converting to float and then to int.

Comment: If you do it that way, don't forget that the decimal delimiter is different on different regional settings. Our French cousins use `,`

Comment: Of course, I thought it was obvious :) In Russia we use commas as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think another way of doing it would be splitting the string into pieces taking the decimal (.) as the delimiter and then parsing for the integer. Of course, I am yet to ask you if the string might contain values like `"37.56 miles in 32.65 seconds"` type values.

Considering there will be only one value (string or number) in the string, I can think of something in the following line:

```
public int64 GetInt64(string input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return 0;
    // Split string on decimal (.)
    // ... This will separate all the digits.
    //
    string[] words = input.Split('.');
    return int.Parse(words[0]);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps no need for int64 return when doing an int32 parse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Visual Basic runtime Library to accomplish this from c#.

You need to add a reference to the assembly Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll to your solution.

Then the following code will do your conversion:

```
using VB = Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = VB.Conversions.ToInteger("1.2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and ended up using a hybrid of Mark's and Dariusz':

```
 if (num == "")
     {
      num = "0.00";
     }

  var num1 = (float)Convert.ToDouble(num);
```